# Lambda S3 permission denied in s3-get-object blueprint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm trying to get a Lambda to read a file off an S3 bucket using the `s3-get-object` blueprint in response to file `post` events.

Even when the bucket has full public access and full permissions:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1468930000031",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1468929998580",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xlp-uploads/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the Lambda role has full S3 and Lambda access, I still get `Access Denied` when running the example code.

This is the Lambda code in the blueprint:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key
    };
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.`;
            console.log(message);
            callback(message);
        } else {
            console.log('CONTENT TYPE:', data.ContentType);
            callback(null, data.ContentType);
        }
    });
};
```

And the error is:

```
{ [AccessDenied: Access Denied]
  message: 'Access Denied',
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: Tue Jul 19 2016 12:27:28 GMT+0000 (UTC),
```

Comment: Try this answer and see if it works for you, you just have to replace one line in lambda code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605622/access-denied-on-aws-lambda-function-when-getobject-from-s3-bucket/35608375#35608375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the issue out.

I initially tried to POST the file to S3 using the REST API but the file ends up in the bucket with no permissions and does not inherit the bucket's permissions.

I switched to a POST request that accepts ACL parameters and gives the file permissions in place.