# Create Policy in Cloudformation Granting Access to s3 Buckets From Separate AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have read the "Specifying Principals in a Policy" doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html, and am inferring some behaviors from there and other SO (like [aws lambda function getting access denied when getObject from s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589641/aws-lambda-function-getting-access-denied-when-getobject-from-s3)) questions that do not specifically deal with Cloudformation.

I am still stumped on this error when I try to create a policy that grants a foreign role access to a local bucket. The error from Cloudformation is: `Policy document should not specify a principal.`

#### Situation Breakdown

I  have two AWS accounts. Account A creates a bucket, and I want to grant Account B write access to it.

**In Account A Cloudformation** I have created a Policy that that grants an Account B role access to said bucket. Guide from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html. That role exists for Account B.

`AccountBWriteToS3Policy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: AccountBWriteToS3Policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Principal:
              AWS: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789876:role/AccountBRole'
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 's3:PutObject'
              - 's3:ListBucket'
            Resource: !Sub 
              - '${bucketArn}/*'
              - bucketArn: !GetAtt 
                  - AccountABucket
                  - Arn
      Roles:
        - AccountARole`

However, cloudformation fails to execute, and rolls back with an error 
`Policy document should not specify a principal.`

I'm fairly stumped.

**Can anyone explain this error?**

**Can anyone prescribe a path forward?**

This seems like a simple and common need, covered in numerous examples. Maybe I'm supposed to specify the policy within the bucket declaration itself instead of creating an account-wide policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create a role with "Trust policy" with the principle and then a "permission policy" to allow read/write access to the S3 Bucket.

Here is a snippet from my Cloudformation.

```
  Role:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${RuleName}-Role'
      Path: "/"     
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AccountID}:user/*'
          Action: sts:AssumeRole      
  RolePolicies:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Sub '${RuleName}-RolePolicies'
      Roles:
        - Ref: "Role"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:       
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - s3:Get*
          - s3:Put*
          - s3:List*
          - s3:AbortMultipartUpload       
          Resource:
          - !Ref Bucket
```

Ref: [Cross account tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

Comment: That did it, thanks! It appears like Roles can have principals (which could be other roles), and policies only specify actions